# WFS layer in Openlayers 3 does not work

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a PostGIS-type layer in Geoserver. I use Openlayers 3.9.0 to get it on my map. My code is based on the official [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=wfs).

```
var map = new ol.Map({...//set the map

var textent = ol.proj.transformExtent([2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857');
var resolution =  map.getView().getResolution();
var  projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(textent, resolution, projection) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mymap/wfs?&service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:mylayer&outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=100'
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}))
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

map.addLayer(vector);
```

I dont quite get what this code does, the example does not explain.  I dont know what this `url: function(textent, resolution, projection) {` actually does. Also, do I need to set a seperate function for loading features like `function loadFeatures(response) {...` or this will happen automatically?

When I execute the code, I get `GET http://localhost:5550/undefined 404 (Not Found)     ol-debug.js:69863` 28 times. The `ol-debug.js` line is `this.xhr_.send(content);`. The Node server is on port 5550 and Geoserver is on port 8080 and I have set a reverse proxy on Node to avoid CORS and ACAO errors.

Please, I need to understand and debug.

Thanks

**More Info**

In Geoserver, when I choose `GeoJSON` to preview this layer, the URL is `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mymap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:mylayer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson`. I set this as the URL of vector source and still get the same errors.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html?

Comment: @AlvinLindstam OK, so `ol.FeatureLoader()` loads features from a source,but does load them on the map also? Any tips on the 404 errors? Thanks again